# My sticky nav has the highest z-index, but is still getting trespassed. Can any of you see my problem?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm making a project with a big image at the top of the page, followed by a sticky nav.

The info following the nav keeps trespassing!

I have been trying all sorts of things, making the other sections after it have a lower or negative z-index numbers, as well as trying to set the opacity to 99 for the following modules because I read that opacity changes the stacking order.

```css
/*Navigation*/

navigation {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px #326559;
}

.z {
  position: relative;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 500;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav img {
  max-width: 9vw;
}


/*Annonce*/

.annonce {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .99;
}

.annonce p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.annonce img {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/*Location Gallery*/

hr {
  background-color: #326557;
  height: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

location-card {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #326557;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #e5fbe2;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<navigation class="z">
  <inner-column>
    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="icon">
        <img src="images/bla.png">
      </a>
      <a href="#">Sign in</a>
    </nav>
  </inner-column>
</navigation>


<main>

  <section class="annonce">
    <inner-column>
      <p>Bla bla bla!</p>
    </inner-column>

    <picture>
      <img src="images/image1.jpg">
    </picture>
  </section>

  <?php include('locationCards.php'); ?>
```

[Working on my sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5grb.jpg)

I'm going to include my html for the nav.
And a little bit of what comes after that.

I'm including some CSS for both the nav and what comes after, in case another more skilled person can see what my issue is.

Thanks so much

Comment: give a background to .z, so you do not see through it ;)

Comment: Exactly:) Your sticky header is not transparent. Add a background color.

Comment: Your nav has no background, therefor you are seeing the content rolling by below the sticky element.

Comment: Oh my goodness, such an easy fix. Thank you all so much. Still learning what to look out for here.

Answer (score -1):

I have already created a site like that, You can search it on google using keywords. "Sticky Navbar".

 and I'm going to share my code with you too.

```js
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= 30) {
        header.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
header .logo{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header .nav{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
header .nav li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height:100%;
}
header .nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
}
header.sticky{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0,0.5);
    height:3.75rem;
}
header.sticky .logo{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
header.sticky ul{
    height:100%;
}
header.sticky ul li{
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
header.sticky ul li a{
    color:rgb(204, 34, 34);
}
header.sticky .nav li:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff0157;
}
p{
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #111;
}
.ban{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 600px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;     
     background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.35)),url('https://winteriscoming.net/files/2021/01/thor-4-marvel-chris-hemsworth.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size:cover;
     background-position:left;
}
.ban .box{
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ban .box h3{
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #fff;
}
.ban .box p{
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <a href="#ban" class="logo">Avenger</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#ban">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#expert">Expert</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
 
  <section class="ban" id="ban">
    <div class="box">
      <h3>Always Choose Good</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam sit nemo blanditiis tenetur, autem enim
        similique dolor saepe earum consequuntur.</p>
      <a href="#menu" class="bnt">Our Menu</a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I think this will help you more!